# Can you use more than one instrumental variables in an Econometric model?

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variable

Can you use two instrumental variables $z_1$ and $z_2$ at the same time for $x_1$ and $x_2$, in the following regression model

$y=a+bx_1+cx_2+dX_{other}+e$, where

$y$ is the explained variable,

$x_1$ and $x_2$ are two variables of interest that you want to study but are endogenous,

$X_{other}$ are other exogenous control variables,

$e$ is the error term.

Comment: Yes. In that case, technically, the instrumental variables are $z_1$, $z_2$ and $X_{other}$. The exogeneity requirement is clear. The relevance condition is more complicated when there are multiple (in your case, two) endogenous regressors. See `help ivregress_postestimation` (`estat firststage`) of Stata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have endogeneity between a dependent variable and error term the use of Instrument variables are the way to go.

as long as $\mathbf{COV}(x_1,z_1)\ne0,\mathbf{COV}(x_2,z_2)\ne0,\mathbf{COV}(z_2,e)=0$ and $\mathbf{COV}(z_1,e)=0$ you can do so.

Comment: Isn't it also required that $z_1,z_2$ are uncorrelated with $X_{other}$?

Comment: @AdamBailey the issue is _perfect_ multicollinearity. as long as the correlation between all combinations of $z_1,z_2$  and $X_{other}$ are not 1 or -1, its good.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity#Definition

Comment: @EconJohn I think you meant to say COV(z2,e)=0 whereas you said COV(z1,e)=0 twice. Also more generally you could allow for Cov(x1, z2)≠0 and Cov(x2, z1)≠0. The point is as long as there are as many instruments that are informative as there are variables that are endogenous (ie the rank condition)

Comment: @AndrewM you are correct.  edited

Comment: Thanks @EconJohn for your time.  what is your comments on "**Models with multiple endogenous variables are indeed hard to identify and the results can be hard to interpret.

So we don’t usually like to see them – for one thing it’s not clear why you’re tackling two causal questions at the same time; one is hard enough.**" from http://www.mostlyharmlesseconometrics.com/2010/02/multiple-endogenous-variables-what-now/

Comment: @MaxShang  The blog post is valid. However if you have strong instruments, I don;t think it should be an issue with using more than one.

Comment: @EconJohn Thanks again for your time. I really appreciate your help.